# How to do Copy and paste the image from User system to Canvas using fabric.js

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

Can we do copy(Ctrl+C) and paste(Ctrl+V) the image from User system(desktop/any folder) to canvas using fabric.js. I have seen the copy and paste program inside the canvas, I have found this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tkfGs/139/) while searching google but didnt find any relevant example for desktop to canvas. Here is the snippet for copy and paste

```
function onKeyDownHandler(event) {
    //event.preventDefault();

    var key;
    if(window.event){
        key = window.event.keyCode;
    }
    else{
        key = event.keyCode;
    }

    switch(key){
        //////////////
        // Shortcuts
        //////////////
        // Copy (Ctrl+C)
        case 67: // Ctrl+C
            if(ableToShortcut()){
                if(event.ctrlKey){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    copy();
                }
            }
            break;
        // Paste (Ctrl+V)
        case 86: // Ctrl+V
            if(ableToShortcut()){
                if(event.ctrlKey){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    paste();
                }
            }
            break;            
        default:
            // TODO
            break;
    }
}


function ableToShortcut(){
    /*
    TODO check all cases for this

    if($("textarea").is(":focus")){
        return false;
    }
    if($(":text").is(":focus")){
        return false;
    }
    */
    return true;
}

function copy(){
    if(canvas.getActiveGroup()){
        for(var i in canvas.getActiveGroup().objects){
            var object = fabric.util.object.clone(canvas.getActiveGroup().objects[i]);
            object.set("top", object.top+5);
            object.set("left", object.left+5);
            copiedObjects[i] = object;
        }                    
    }
    else if(canvas.getActiveObject()){
        var object = fabric.util.object.clone(canvas.getActiveObject());
        object.set("top", object.top+5);
        object.set("left", object.left+5);
        copiedObject = object;
        copiedObjects = new Array();
    }
}

function paste(){
    if(copiedObjects.length > 0){
        for(var i in copiedObjects){
            canvas.add(copiedObjects[i]);
        }                    
    }
    else if(copiedObject){
        canvas.add(copiedObject);
    }
    canvas.renderAll();    
}
```

Is it possible to do actually I have heard dat it's may not possible.Can anyone guide me how to do please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're targeting modern browsers you can combine 2 new (but widely adopted) html5 features to accomplish your task:

1. You can create a dropzone on your page using the `dragover` and `drop` events.
2. Then you can use the FileReader  API to read the image files into an image object.
3. Then it's back to FabricJS to load the image as usual.

Here's a tutorial describing how to do the hard bits (#1,#2):  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

**[ Added code that SOMETIMES allows cut/paste of image files ]**

Most modern browsers support binding the “paste” event.

```
// listen for the paste event
window.addEventListener("paste",pasteImage);
```

But...!!

Support for non-text mime types (ie “image”) is scarce.   Chrome seems to support it “off-and-on”.

…And browsers are constantly revising their cut/paste capabilities because of security concerns.

Here is code that sometimes works in Chrome.

```
// listen for the paste event
window.addEventListener("paste",pasteImage);

function pasteImage(event) {

    // get the raw clipboardData
    var cbData=event.clipboardData;

    for(var i=0;i<cbData.items.length;i++){

        // get the clipboard item
        var cbDataItem = cbData.items[i];
        var type = cbDataItem.type;

        // warning: most browsers don't support image data type
        if (type.indexOf("image")!=-1) {
            // grab the imageData (as a blob)
            var imageData = cbDataItem.getAsFile();
            // format the imageData into a URL
            var imageURL=window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(imageData);
            // We've got an imageURL, add code to use it as needed
            // the imageURL can be used as src for an Image object
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply @markE I have already checked this site. Can we do using copy and past keywords from user system to canvas, from above link i tried for drag and drop but its not working properly.

Comment: Added cut/paste code that **might** work in Chrome.  But generally, browsers do not allow cut/paste for security reasons.

Comment: thanks as we have requirement to do copy and paste at the same time drag and drop but main priority was copy/paste only.

Comment: it shows only paste code is this enuf or should write copy code also separately

Comment: The copy-to-clipboard part is handled by the operating system (user keyboards [Copy] on an image file—eg Ctrl+C in Windows).  No coding is required on your part for the copy.  This code grabs everything that’s been copied to the clipboard and tries to find images.  Again, browser support for this paste code is limited and transitory.  BTW,  what problem did you have with the drag/drop link? (it usually works fine in modern browsers except IE—argh IE!).

Comment: I don't have any prob but client asked us to do like this if copy/paste doesn't work our next step to do drag and drop only I have tried for drag n drop but it seems not working properly

Comment: Yes, as I warned, the paste code was a “long-shot” due to browser security concerns..  Hmmm...drag/drop works fine for me in Chrome-27 & FF-21 (not IE).  What I get is the meta-data for the image that is dropped to the “Drop files here” drop zone. Meta-data: cityscape.png (image/png) - 243324 bytes, last modified: 6/1/2013.  Is your experience different?

Comment: I am using http://jsfiddle.net/natchiketa/w8kkc/ this code for drag and drop but some what it is not working

Comment: from above comment jsfiddle code like that i want to work for desktop to canvas can u refer some tutorials to do like that

Comment: after dropping in to canvas the image should work like in other images which are in built in code

Comment: @markE sounds interesting (the second option) would you mind to put together a little fiddle where the fabric.js part is handled? That would be extremely useful - and awesome...